# apt-get update not working (Not Found [IP: 194.19.194.51 80])

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, software-sources

Hi I have issues with my apt-get update, I've tried to replace all entries of archive with old-releases in sources.list with no success.

```
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/libopencv4tegra-repo  InRelease
Ign:2 file:/var/libopencv4tegra-repo  InRelease         
Get:3 file:/var/visionworks-repo  InRelease             
Ign:3 file:/var/visionworks-repo  InRelease
Get:4 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  InRelease                                                                   
Ign:4 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  InRelease                                                                   
Get:5 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  InRelease                                                              
Ign:5 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  InRelease                                                              
Get:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  Release [574 B]                                                              
Get:7 file:/var/libopencv4tegra-repo  Release [347 B]                                                             
Get:8 file:/var/visionworks-repo  Release [1,999 B]                                                               
Get:9 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  Release [2,003 B]                                                           
Get:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local  Release [574 B]                                                              
Get:10 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  Release [2,008 B]                                                     
Get:7 file:/var/libopencv4tegra-repo  Release [347 B]                                                             
Get:8 file:/var/visionworks-repo  Release [1,999 B]                                                               
Get:9 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  Release [2,003 B]                                                           
Get:10 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  Release [2,008 B]                                                     
Hit:11 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                       
Ign:13 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                                                             
Ign:15 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                     
Get:12 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                                      
Hit:17 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release                                                               
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aguignard/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                             
Hit:20 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                       
Hit:21 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                             
Get:14 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]                           
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]        
Ign:26 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages                            
Ign:27 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:28 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:26 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
Ign:27 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:28 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:26 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
Ign:27 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:28 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Err:26 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.19.194.51 80]
Ign:27 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:28 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Get:31 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [593 kB]
Get:32 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [573 kB]
Ign:33 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages
Get:34 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [240 kB]
Get:35 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [304 kB]
Get:36 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [203 kB]    
Get:37 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [510 kB]
Get:38 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [493 kB]
Ign:39 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages     
Get:40 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [198 kB]
Get:41 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [163 kB]
Get:42 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [212 kB]
Get:43 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [15.5 kB]
Get:44 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.6 kB]
Ign:45 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages     
Get:46 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7,540 B]
Get:47 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,892 B]
Ign:48 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
Get:49 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,324 B]
Hit:50 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Get:51 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [5,808 B]     
Get:52 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages [5,816 B]                   
Ign:53 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages                            
Get:54 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,688 B]           
Get:55 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,715 B]                 
Ign:33 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages                                     
Ign:39 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:45 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages                    
Ign:48 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages                        
Ign:53 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages                    
Ign:33 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages                          
Ign:39 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages                      
Ign:45 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages                    
Get:56 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [316 kB]                  
Ign:48 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages                                   
Ign:53 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Err:33 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.19.194.51 80]
Ign:39 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:45 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Err:48 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.19.194.51 80]
Ign:53 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Get:57 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [298 kB]
Ign:58 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
Get:59 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [133 kB]
Get:60 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [59.2 kB]
Get:61 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [49.6 kB]
Get:62 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [149 kB]
Get:63 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [133 kB]
Ign:64 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:65 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [77.0 kB]
Get:66 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.7 kB]
Get:67 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [56.2 kB]
Ign:58 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:64 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:58 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:64 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Err:58 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:64 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Fetched 306 kB in 0s (363 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/_var_libopencv4tegra-repo_Release
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
E: Failed to fetch http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 194.19.194.51 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 194.19.194.51 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 194.19.194.51 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is my sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

During comments and chat we figured, the problem was with how nvidia implemented the cross-compiling installation for Jetpacks: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1003434/ubuntu-14-04-16-04-and-jetpack-3-0/

to fix the issue the above link suggests to

```
sudo apt-get purge ".*:arm64"
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64
```

Another step to take was to explicitly set all source links to the correct architecture:  (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#advanced-setup)

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] <url>
```

Comment: I've tried to add your lines but I still get errors (Not Found [IP: xx.xxx.xx.xxx 80]) My architecture on my pc is amd64 honestly I don't know when the error started occurring in my update, but I think it have something to do with nvidia jetson tx2 board and their jetpack maybe.

Comment: if your architecture is ``amd64``, you should not use ports mirrors, but replace ``arm64`` in your ``/etc/apt/sources.list`` with ``amd64``

Comment: I've commented all lines so only the one you listed is uncommented, still I about 5 errors of `E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]`

Comment: The new answer doesn't work either, there are no where in my souces.list where amd64 or arm64 is specified, so there is nothing to replace.

Comment: that is most curious, where is your apt getting those arm64 info from? are there any files in ``/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`` ?

Comment: Yea plenty, I will look through them and report back, I guess I should replace the archive.ubuntu.com with ports.ubuntu.com in the conflicting file?

Comment: no, you should replace any ``[arch=arm64]`` with ``[arch=amd64]`` - 
forget about the ports mirrors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63204/discussion-between-mikeyr-and-phillip-zyan-k-lee-stockmann).