# rebooting loop on ubuntu 16.04 after removing arm64

Tags: 16.04, wine, reboot, arm64

We were working on installing Wine. We found out that there might be the problem with arm64 so we followed this instruction 
[apt-get update not working (Not Found [IP: 194.19.194.51 80])](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942155/apt-get-update-not-working-not-found-ip-194-19-194-51-80/942157#942157a)
The above tabs disappeared. We unplugged the system in order to reboot it.
Now we are struck with the rebooting loop as show in this image [Rebooting in 5 seconds..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCDy4.jpg)

Please help us to get our system working again

Thank you